# Solving many tiny linear programming problems quickly on embedded

Tags: android, c++, ios, optimization, linear-programming

As part of some live rendering process for a program that runs on iOS/Android, written in C/C++, I need to solve many tiny linear programming problems, with 5 variables and 2 constraints, i.e.

```
minimize: a_0*x + b_0*y + c_0*z + d_0*u + e_0*v
subject to:
  p_1 = a_1*x + b_1*y + c_1*z + d_1*u + e_1*v
  p_2 = a_2*x + b_2*y + c_2*z + d_2*u + e_2*v
  0 <= x <= x_max
  0 <= y <= y_max
  0 <= z <= z_max
  0 <= u <= u_max
  0 <= v <= v_max
```

I'd like to solve this quickly using a permissive license.

Searching I found Google's linear optimization library [glop](https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/master/src/glop) (Apache2), but

1. it is a fairly big dependency, 7MB of code for something so small
2. I'm concerned about the overhead of setting up the LP problems.

I feel it should be possible to solve this directly, by just enumerating the vertices and testing the objective function, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Is there a tiny LP library with small overhead I could use? Or alternatively, how would I break down the math?

Comment: How about [GLPK](https://www.gnu.org/software/glpk/)?

Comment: Would love to use GLPK. Unfortunately for my current purpose, it's GPL.

Comment: I think you should ask in a math forum if there's no direct solution to this.

Comment: It's hard to find something free and non-GPL as far as LP solvers are concerned. There is COIN-OR as well, it's distributed under Eclipse Public License.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution can reasonably be hard-coded as follows:

- take the first two linear constraints and select three variables (there are 10 ways to do so), to which you assign either 0 or max (there are 8 ways to do that). This leads to 10 elementary 2x2 systems, with 8 different right-hand sides.
- check if these solutions are admissible (the two computed unknowns in range 0 to max).
- keep the admissible solution that minimizes the objective.

I wouldn't be surprised that carefully micro-optimized and unrolled code can beat a general-purpose solver (simplex algorithm).

Comment: Thanks! In the end I came up with something like that as well. I'm hoping that it'll be fast enough. For 5 variables, it creates 80 feasibility tests, which sounds kind of crazy.

Comment: @Ant6n: the simplex would probably avoid a part of these tests, at the expense of decision logics overhead.

Comment: Btw, good call on calling it 10 systems with 8 different right hand sides each. This means when using cramers rule, the inverse determinant of the non-fixed variables has to be only computed 10 times, rather than 80 times.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use [Sensitivity Analysis for Linear Programming](http://web.mit.edu/15.053/www/AMP-Chapter-03.pdf) (example with Excel is [here](http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/or/lpsens_solver.html)). The idea is to solve LP: `min{ cx: Ax>= b }` for a given input `(c,A,b)` and find the parameter ranges (using formulas from the link above) for which the solution remains optimal. If you know the approximate possible bounds on your parameters then it's a matter of solving a number of LPs and storing ranges and solutions.

Comment: This is a neat (albeit complicated) idea to try to reduce the number of vertices of the feasible area to search. Unfortunately for my specific problem, the bounds on the variables are too large, so any of the vertices could be the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your feasible set is a hypercube in 5 dimensions being sliced by two planes. It is small enough to be represented in a different form - as a combination of extreme vertices. The vertices can be enumerated, and the optimal can be found by simply evaluating the objective function in each vertex.

If your plane coefficients change, you can start with the 32 vertices that define the hypercube as the combination of extreme vertices.

You need to write some code to slice a region (polytope) represented by extreme vertices against a plane.

Since you only slice it twice, this will not add too many extra vertices.